# VNC control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, vnc, vnc-viewer

i am looking for a vnc control (Client) i would be able to use inside a WPF application i am creating .

I would like to to be able to capture computes with TightVNC/UltraVNC (open source types) servers.

Anything like that exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know only [VncSharp](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/) that is a Winform control but maybe you can adapt to WPF ... Take a look at [this](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/horus531/20110515/1305443108) porting to WPF for example ...

Comment: Thanks for your response! VncSharp has large delays and is not very successful when compared to an actual vnc client. I was hoping for something better.